# Angular HTML select form showing only the first choice

Tags: html, angular, forms, select

So guys, I have this very simple snippet

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"  (change)="onChooseMenuItem($event.target.value)">
    <option selected disabled>Please select a program</option>
    <option
      style="cursor: pointer"
      *ngFor="let menuItem of ngrxMenuItems, let i = index"
      value={{i}}
    >{{menuItem.type}}
      </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

when i make a choice it always shows me the first option as selected. Let's say `ngrxMenuItems` is an array with [1,2,3,4]. No matter what is the choice you make it will show you only the first option.

What i tried: 
 - removing (change)="onChooseMenuItem($event.target.value)" and replacing it with (click) event on every row
 - trying ngIf options

What I assume it is:
 = Some Angular behaviour I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You main problem is here `(change)="onChooseMenuItem($event.target.value)`, the reason being that the `target` property does not exist on the `$event` emitted event, you need to handle the value part in the ts method like so

Html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"  (change)="onChooseMenuItem($event)"> <!-- Change the (change) event emitter -->
    <option selected disabled>Please select a program</option>
    <option
      style="cursor: pointer"
      *ngFor="let menuItem of ngrxMenuItems, let i = index"
      value={{i}}
    >{{menuItem.type}}
      </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Ts

```
onChooseMenuItem(event: any){
  const value = event.target.value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not bind a value from your component to your selection.
So select does not know which values is the actual to select as option.

You must add ngModel to your select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" [(ngModel)]="select1">
<option selected disabled>Please select a program</option>
<option
  style="cursor: pointer"
  *ngFor="let menuItem of ngrxMenuItems, let i = index"
  value={{i}}
>{{menuItem.type}}
  </option>
```

'select1' is a variable in your component containing the information about the selected option.